# Unable to load DLL, AssemblyResolve in Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'm having an issue changing a working app into a service and i think it maybe to do with `AssemblyResolve` is called.

My code:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        SubscribeAssemblyResolver();
        ExecuteApplication();
    }

    private static void SubscribeAssemblyResolver()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }

    static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var name = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;
        if (name == "dllname")
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(instanceBinPath, name + ".dll"));
        }
        else
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    private static void ExecuteApplication()
    {
        if (live)
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Testing());
        }
    }
```

As you can see I use a live bool when building to change it from an app to a service for testing, so all the code is the same but when it runs (installs fine) as a service I get an

> Unable to load DLL 'tcxpscom_native': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)    exception.

Does the `AssemblyResolve` event trigger different when it's a service? or should the code be moved somewhere else and not called in the main()?

---

***UPDATE***
I have done some testing on the  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and found that the dll i'm looking for doesn't have an event.

Any suggestion why this would happen when running as a service but work work fine as an app?

Comment: I suppose the word "native" is relevant in the DLL name.  Unmanaged DLLs do not trigger the AssemblyResolve event and cannot be loaded with Load().  Keep it in the same directory as the EXE so the OS can find it.

Comment: Thanks Hans you managed to point me in the right direction, but it turns out the issue is because the installer is automatically including the dll file in the exe folder. Removing it and it works. Can't work out why it's included as nothing is set to and when it builds it's not there in the debug or release folders.